# Is There A Way To Add Emmet To A HTML File

Tags: html, emmet

I want to add emmet to my html file. So basically I have a div with  the contenteditable attribute set to true and I want to be able to use emmet in it. Is there a way? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/emmetio/textarea

Comment: I don't have node and don't want to use it, or is there a way to add it without require and no node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to add emmet to the editable div? If so, that is not possible. The `contenteditable` attribute just provides WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) experience by providing in-browser **rich-text**.

Emmet however is a set of plugins in editors to improve the coding workflow.

You could check [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) to see more about the `contenteditable` attribute

Comment: I'm fine with a textarea too

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use Emmet in your editor/IDE?  Emmet is an extension to common editors to help make writing HTML & CSS easier.

Comment: no like adding it to an actual HTML file(specifically div)